# Was 'diff' included in the first version of Linux

Tags: linux, diff, history

What is the list of programs that were available in the first public version of Linux distribution (not just kernel)? I am specially concerned when this distribution was released and if `diff` utility was there.

Comment: What do you mean by Linux here? The first public version of Linux was just a kernel, it didn't have any utilities at all, so this question doesn't make much sense. Also, as a 2 second search would have shown you, ["The diff utility was developed in the early 1970s on the Unix operating system which was emerging from Bell Labs in Murray Hill, New Jersey. The final version, first shipped with the 5th Edition of Unix in 1974, was entirely written by Douglas McIlroy."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility).

Comment: @terdon edited the question to mention that by Linux I mean not just kernel. And the question is specifically about Linux.

Comment: Linux is only a kernel. Maybe you meant distribution ?

Comment: Take a look at [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#History). I think that is somewhat hard to find those files nowadays.

Comment: @sebelk thanks. That's a good pointer, but no clear answer. And wikipedia pages still don't have any mention of `diff`.

Comment: Check the [0.01 release notes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/old-versions/RELNOTES-0.01), only `bash` there. The GNU diffutils predate Linux by a few years, so you'd have been able to compile it for that kernel at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - [it did](https://github.com/rdebath/SLS-1.02/blob/master/usr/bin/diff).

A bit of archeology reveals that

1. The first linux distributions were published in [1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#History). SLS 1.02, linked above, was the most popular at the time.
2. GNU bulletin for Jan 1993 includes [diff 2.0](https://www.gnu.org/bulletins/bull14.html#SEC29).

> diff 2.0 GNU diff compares files showing line-by-line changes in
>   several flexible formats. It is much faster than the traditional Unix
>   versions. The "diff" distribution contains diff, diff3, sdiff, and
>   cmp.

The SLS distribution, which later forked to slackware and debian included diff in it's /usr/bin, as linked above.

Comment: Awesome. I edited the question title to accept the answer, because the question is really about `diff`.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) of `diff` explains:

> The diff utility was developed in the early 1970s on the Unix operating system which was emerging from Bell Labs in Murray Hill, New Jersey. The final version, first shipped with the 5th Edition of Unix in 1974, was entirely written by Douglas McIlroy.

The Linux kernel was [first released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Linux#The_creation_of_Linux) as a hobbyist project on the 25th of August 1991. The [first distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#History) appeared shortly after that, in 1992.

Since `diff` was, at that point, already 18 years old, it seems reasonable to assume that at least some of the first distributions did indeed include it. I can't find a comprehensive list of the included software, but I would be very surprised if as basic and mature a tool as `diff` were not included.

The [release notes](http://www.kclug.org/old_archives/linux-activists/1992/nov/3/0493.shtml) of [Yggdrasil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil_Linux/GNU/X), one of the very first distributions, state that it included:

> GNU utilities, including GNU C and C++, the GNU 
>                     debugger, bison, flex, GNU make,

While the [GNU diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) are not explicitly mentioned, the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) states that:

> Unified context diffs were originally developed by Wayne Davison in August 1990 (in unidiff which appeared in Volume 14 of comp.sources.misc). Richard Stallman added unified diff support to the GNU Project's diff utility one month later, and the feature debuted in GNU diff 1.15, released in January 1991.

So, the GNU `diff` also predates Linux and, therefore, was almost certainly included with the rest of the GNU tools in the very first distributions.

Comment: The reference to Unix diff is probably not relevant as that code was not free. The diff implementation generally used on Linux is the one from the GNU project (which also predates Linux).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair enough, I added some information on the GNU version.

Comment: That's a great answer, even if it qualifies as "probably yes". =)